# Interpreting a Bayesian Hierarchical model with a center and a difference parameter

Tags: probability, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose we have a Bayesian Model where the data level specification looks like

$$
Y_i \sim Bern(\pi) \\
X_i \sim LogNormal\Big( \alpha_{S_i} + \left[\pi \cdot Y_{S_i} - (1-\pi) \cdot Y_{S_i}\right]\Delta_{S_i}, \sigma^2_{S_i}\Big)
$$

for $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ and $S_i \in \{1, \ldots S\}$

That is, there are $N$ individuals and each individual belongs to one of $S$ subgroups.

I am trying to understand why this model might be useful. The $\alpha$ appears to represent the overall mean, while the $\delta$ controls the differences in mean between $Y=1$ and $Y=0$. However, I am not sure what the $\left[\pi \cdot Y_{S_i} - (1-\pi) \cdot Y_{S_i}\right]$ term in front of the $\Delta_{S_i}$ is doing. Could anyone give some insight to this?